# Where should people asking for open-source-work be directed to?

Tags: discussion

This question was asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139232/c-sharp-and-asp-net-mvc-open-source-project-which-i-can-contribute-to

As far as I'm aware, this does not belong on StackOverflow, but where does it belong to? Is there a place in the StackExchange-community for this kind of requests?

Comment: I would say that this is not a good fit for any of the sites within the network. It will always be of the "not constructive" type, if it doesn't fall under any of the other closure reasons already.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/? Not for this particular one, though.

Comment: No, it does not belong anywhere on the network...do we look like a personalized searchmachine?

Comment: @Gnoupi: Interesting idea, though. Does Careers have a functionality to allow to be recruited for FLOSS projects...in some sort?

Comment: @Gnoupi Is Careers still invitation only? If so, that might also not always work.

Comment: The [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296422/looking-for-a-good-c-sharp-open-source-project) referred to in the comments should probably be closed as well.

Comment: @Bart: It is indeed still invitation-only.

Comment: And [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392947/what-is-a-good-open-source-c-sharp-project-for-me-to-get-involved-in), again used to justify keeping this one open.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Huh?  Your links don't work.  I think you imagined that.

Comment: @Won't All the questions mentioned have been deleted after they were mentioned here. I personally saw them working when they were posted.

Comment: @AskeB.: **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby Thinking it was a good idea as well, I forwarded it to the proposals site: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/6291/open-source-version-of-careers-stackoverflow

Comment: @AskeB.: See that diamond next to his name? Betcha he can see much more than those questions... Thanks Won't. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah didn't know that, thanks for the heads up. Btw, is it just me or is there a lot of insider humor going on, in general, on these sites - I've even seen questions and answers that were completely irrelevant to the site, but were upvoted (tens and hundreds) for humor. Naturally, I have nothing against humor, but I've rarely seen it as constructive or useful, which is what this site is about, right?.

Comment: @AskeB.: Yeah, there is are some [memes here on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta), but on the whole the humorous responses are reserved for those that have been around for a while and have picked up on them. Don't worry about rep on meta, it is largely irrelevant here, what with all the downvoting being different anyway.

Comment: @AskeB. Humour? No, not us, [we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: @YannisRizos Thanks for the article. I have a critique of it though: All the "fun" questions I have seen have been old. The reason they weren't closed before they became popular was because the rules were different then. By stating that we want "only a limited amount" of fun, you basically say "no fun", since the question is most likely going to be closed as "not constructive" before the question ever becomes popular. This means it's unlikely that informative and productive answers will ever make their way to this question. So as I see it, one-liner comments are the only place for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it would be easiest to just redirect people to [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) or similar, but since I can't really imagine how you could reformat the question to have that answer, without it being a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), there's probably not much to do to prevent them from happening, other than removing or closing the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with other answerers that this doesn't belong on StackOverflow, but I would think a better close reason would have been **Not Constructive**:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but **this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.** If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

*What project should I contribute to* clearly fits into the "questions likely to solicit debate" category in my book.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow and its sister sites do not support questions which are in essence product recommendations. I therefore think that the question you mentioned is not a good fit for any site within the network.

Comment: @gnoupi Why that rollback after your edit?

Comment: @Bart - because I wasn't satisfied of my own edit, didn't really sound correct yet, so I took it away for someone to do a better job than me.